# About `argv` and opening a file with command line

Tags: c, argv, argc

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{    
     FILE *file;
     int x;

     if ( argc != 2 )
           printf( "Use: %s file name", argv[0] );
     else {
            if ((file=fopen( argv[1], "r" ))== 0 ) 
            printf( “Couldn't open the file.\n" );
             else {
                          while (( x = fgetc( file ) ) != EOF)  printf( "%c", x );
                          fclose( file );
              }
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Now, having this code, how do I execute a file from terminal (that is on the pic as well as my configuration of NetBeans). https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WRh3.png

Comment: I absolutely don't understand what you are asking. Is there any link with the code or is that related to one of you tools?

Comment: @OznOg How do I open a file from terminal. It should be something like this `$program file`

Comment: @Beth: if you can afford that, switch to Linux (which is free). It is a nicer work environment to learn programming.

Comment: What operating system? What compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, better replace your statement (in your program above)

```
printf( “Couldn't open the file.\n" );
```

with

```
perror(argv[1]);
```

then, simply *compile* your program in your terminal, e.g. type there a shell command similar to

```
gcc -Wall -g mysource.c -o myprog
```

<sup>(Read more about [*invoking GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html): the `-Wall` option asks for nearly all warnings and is *very useful* -so never miss it-; you could even add `-Wextra` to get even more warnings; the `-g` is asking for [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging information in the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable and enables you to use later `gdb`)</sup>

assuming your source code is in a file named `mysource.c` in the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (use `pwd` command to query that current directory, `ls -al` to list it, and `cd` builtin command to change it)

at last, run your program as

```
./myprog sometestfile.txt
```

You might want to use the [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger). Read first about [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), and try perhaps

```
gdb ./myprog
```

<sup>(**I am guessing you are on Linux** or some other POSIX compliant operating system, **and using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler**)</sup>

Read more about [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [command line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface), [shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29), [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)

Later, you'll want to have some bigger program of yours made in several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29), having some common header file (to be `#include`d in all of them). Then you'll use a builder like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). You could use a good editor like [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs), some version control like [git](http://git-scm.com/), etc...

<sup>(you might realize that NetBeans is not very useful, because you can have even better developing comfort with *your* own *collection* of tools; having the freedom to choose your tools is worthwhile!)</sup>

PS. Perhaps replace `printf( "%c", x );` with the shorter and more efficient `putchar(x);` ...

Comment: In `gcc -Wall -g mysource.c -o myprog` what is `-Wall`?

Comment: `-Wall` ("warnings all") indicates a high warning level. (It doesn't include all possible warnings, though.) Please make it a habit to compile with `-Wall`. It will help you to catch many errors, for example a mismatch of `printf` formats and arguments.

Comment: @MOehm I'm writting `gcc -Wall -g main.c -o CppApplication_1` and says `gcc: error: main.c: No such file or directory`

Comment: Because you are not in the directory containing `main.c`; you should use some `cd` command to go there

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch @MOehm If I had the `CppApplication_1` on `C:\` how I'd put the commands?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. A drive like `C:` is Windows specific. Linux don't have that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch @MOehm If I place the `CppApplication_1` on `C:` I get the same error. `No such file or directory` I don't know how to use `pwd` or `cd` to get there. (I'm currently working at Windows, I said I placed it on `C:` to give an example).

Comment: I never used Windows. In the old 1985 MSDOS days you might have typed  `C:` as a single command, but I don't understand that question (you should ask another one, and mention which operating system you are using. I hope it is Linux or some POSIX compliant system ....)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If I have `CppApplication_1` on `Desktop` How I write the command to execute properly.

Comment: I cannot help about Windows, and I strongly recommend installing Linux if you are studying computer science or information technology (use Windows for games; have some dual boot system if you need to play)

Comment: If you have a Linux or POSIX system, learn to use the shell (using `cd`, `pwd`, `ls -l` commands....). But that is another question. If you are forced to use Windows, you have my pity (but I cannot help, I'm using Unix since 1987, Linux since 1993, and never coded on Windows)

Comment: Maybe you want to `cd $HOME/Desktop`, but I am only guessing (and that works on Linux, not on Windows). I cannot help about Windows, and I recommend avoiding it (except perhaps for games).